# Why does this typescript template return never?

Tags: typescript

As seen in this typescript playground:

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7APIIMoQMYHsB2AJgDx5FzBwEA0UAKgIy10BMAfFALxRmEVX4oEAB7AIRJFHwQAbhARQA-PQZQAXPRYAoLaEhQAZrlxcps+UNHjCk6XIXKAFAEouHAOQALOO-VRHAIYIAOYMGnbyrpwe3u664NAA7sAGpvDIaJg4BCQRCLQublBePgVBoeHmCFExPmxAA)

```
type FirstOrSecond<condition, T1, T2> = condition extends never ? T1 : T2

type foo = never extends never ? () => 'hi' : (arg1: never) => 'hi'
type wtf = FirstOrSecond<never, () => 'hi', (arg1: never) => 'hi'>
```

The generic `FirstOrSecond` assigns `never` to the `wtf` variable, whereas the explicit definition of `foo` assigns `() => 'hi'` as the type.

Why does the generic freak out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).  [This is intentional](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23022).

Usually applied workaround is to wrap types into single-member tuple in the condition:

```
type FirstOrSecond<condition, T1, T2> = [condition] extends [never] ? T1 : T2
```